# Placing same map w/KML twice on page with different center and zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to place two maps with a KMLLayer side-by-side. I have been able to get the maps to appear but they both use the same center lat/long i.e the lat/long is not being honored for the second map. I want to zoom in to the lower left of the first map 35.04, -120.56 to display more detail. How can I center/zoom the second map?

I'm new to Fiddle - hopefully works:
http://jsfiddle.net/BobH_SLOAPCD/d427zc46/4/

Map script

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.3, -120.3);

  var mapOptions = {
    maxZoom: 12,
    minZoom: 7,
    center: myLatlng,
    preserveViewport: true
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);

  var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.slocleanair.org/air/AQI_III/AQI_2015_yy_yy.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map
  });

  var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(34.9, -120.5);

  var mapOptions2 = {
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 8,
    zoom: 9,
    center: myLatlng2,
    preserveViewport: true
  };

  var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'),
  mapOptions2);

  var kmlLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://www.slocleanair.org/air/AQI_III/AQI_2015_yy_yy.kml',
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    map: map2
  });
}
initialize();
```

HTML:

```
 <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <p>Test KML Layers</p>
 <div id="map-canvas"></div>
 <div id="map-canvas2"></div>
```

CSS

```
#map-canvas {
  width: 260px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
  float:left;
}
#map-canvas2 {
  width: 260px;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #999;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preserveViewport option is a [KmlLayers](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) option, not a [google.maps.Map option](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).  Note that if you use preserveViewport for *both* of the KmlLayers, you need to set the two mandatory options for the map (zoom and center).

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d427zc46/5/)

working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(35.3, -120.3);

    var mapOptions = {
        maxZoom: 12,
        minZoom: 7,
        center: myLatlng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.slocleanair.org/air/AQI_III/AQI_2015_yy_yy.kml',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map,
        // preserveViewport: true
    });

    var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(34.9, -120.5);

    var mapOptions2 = {
        maxZoom: 18,
        minZoom: 8,
        zoom: 9,
        center: myLatlng2
    };

    var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas2'),
    mapOptions2);

    var kmlLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://www.slocleanair.org/air/AQI_III/AQI_2015_yy_yy.kml',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map2,
        preserveViewport: true
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
    width: 260px;
    height: 180px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
    float:left;
}
#map-canvas2 {
    width: 260px;
    height: 180px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<p>Test KML Layers</p>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="map-canvas2"></div>
<p>Big Map</p>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to "zoom" to 7.5? I did a GetBounds() ((35.03904360033429, -121.31006804474668),
(35.71088896142096, -120.21143523224668)) but I don't see a way to SetBounds().

Comment: Nope.  Zoom levels are integers.  I don't understand what you mean by not seeing a way to set bounds, that method is called fitBounds().

Comment: fitBounds() may work if I display the full extents - not sure of that as I think fitBounds() may just pick the zoom level that doesn't clip the map. The case I am thinking of is my second map that is zoomed into a portion of a full map. I'd like to not be restricted to the center + zoom level - may not be practical given the nature of a tile server. Just wishing I guess. not critical.